# How can i put my class in the client in socket programming?

Tags: java, serversocket, flappy-bird-clone

I made a game similar to Flappy Bird by using JavaFX. Now I want to play it by using localhost IP.
How can I move the class in FlappyBird to the client so that the flappybird becomes the client?

also how can we make multiple clients using this?
This code is a simple one i made with simple concept behind it but what i don't understand is how can i make a class as in a game of flappy bird in the socket programming. How do i implement everything from the flappy bird to the client so the client becomes a flappy bird object

**Client**:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class FlappyClient 
{ 
    // initialize socket and input output streams 
    private Socket socket            = null; 
    private DataInputStream  input   = null; 
    private DataOutputStream out     = null; 
  
    // constructor to put ip address and port 
    public FlappyClient(String address, int port) 
    { 
        // establish a connection 
        try
        { 
            socket = new Socket(address, port); 
            System.out.println("Connected"); 
  
            // takes input from terminal 
            input  = new DataInputStream(System.in); 
  
            // sends output to the socket 
            out    = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        } 
        catch(UnknownHostException u) 
        { 
            System.out.println(u); 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
  
        //=============
        // close the connection 
        try
        { 
            input.close(); 
            out.close(); 
            socket.close(); 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        FlappyClient client = new FlappyClient("localhost", 5000); 
    } 
} 

````````````````````````````````````````````````

````````````````````````````````````````````````
public class FlappyServer 
{ 
    //initialize socket and input stream 
    private Socket          socket   = null; 
    private ServerSocket    server   = null; 
    private DataInputStream in       =  null; 
  
    // constructor with port 
    public FlappyServer(int port) 
    { 
        // starts server and waits for a connection 
        try
        { 
            server = new ServerSocket(port); 
            System.out.println("Server started"); 
  
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
  
            socket = server.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Client accepted"); 
  
            // takes input from the client socket 
            in = new DataInputStream( 
                new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())); 
  
            String line = ""; 
  
            // reads message from client until "Over" is sent 
            while (!line.equals("Over")) 
            { 
                try
                { 
                    line = in.readUTF(); 
                    System.out.println(line); 
  
                } 
                catch(IOException i) 
                { 
                    System.out.println(i); 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println("Closing connection"); 
  
            // close connection 
            socket.close(); 
            in.close(); 
        } 
        catch(IOException i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
    } 
  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        FlappyServer server = new FlappyServer(5000); 
    } 
} 

`````````````````````````````````````````````


**The flappy bird class is too big. Lets call it FlappyBird I want to make this flappybird a client for the server**
`````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to write new code to integrate with a different IP system. Is that correct? If Yes then explain what you have tried and where you are failing in that.

Comment: Please share some code sections where we can help. In current state shows no code which we can help with

Comment: Sorry. I am a bit lost, i have added my server and client code. couldn't add the whole my flappy bird clone source code since it is too big. @AshishKarn No i don't want with different ip system. What i want is to integrate flappybird class to the client.

Comment: @Mohit I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

Main.main(null);